# Post score showing inconsistently on flag history page and general layout wonkiness

Tags: bug, design, flag-history, score

Starting a few minutes ago, I noticed that my flag history on multiple sites now shows post score for only some flagged posts rather than all of them, as was the previous behavior. Considering the unusual and awkward formatting now present, this looks like a bug.

[image: Flag history screenshot with formatting and content issues, enhanced with red circles and with current usernames redacted.]

- Microsoft Windows 8 (6.9.9600)
- Firefox 73.0.1 (64 bit)

Comment: Related: [Today's CSS update broke flag page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394509/4642212).

Answer (score -1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The bug is fixed now.

[image]